# AWS Cost Explorer get-cost-and-usage get cost&usage of each single resources without grouping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-billing

I am trying to list out cost and usage for each single resource in my AWS console such as RDS tables, SQS queues and Lambda functions using Cost Explorer.

I have read the general doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/get-cost-and-usage.html

And this AWS CLI command returns list of cost/usage records `grouped by service type`

```
aws ce get-cost-and-usage \
    --time-period Start=2020-01-01,End=2020-02-01 \
    --granularity MONTHLY \
    --metrics "BlendedCost" "UnblendedCost" "UsageQuantity" \
    --group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE Type=LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME,Key=Environment
```

I have been trying to tweak the command to get a list of cost/usage records of all resources **without grouping** but there is no luck yet. Can anyone help me to correct my command?

Comment: I think you should download the cost and usage report (CUR) which gives the detailed billings by csv files and investigate by yourself. You could import it to Athena and just query for your usage.

Answer (score -5):

The command you are looking for is:
aws cli get-cost-and-usage-with-resources

You can run

```
aws cli get-cost-and-usage-with-resources help
```

for usage help

Comment: If anyone wonders why this was voted down, I think it's because this command is limited to the service "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud – Compute service" (see [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetCostAndUsageWithResources.html)). So it will not help you figuring out costs of anything but EC2 instances.